# Data value not found in console

Tags: php, jquery

```
 var name = this.value ;
 alert(name);
 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/dt-the7/home.php",
data :name,
success: function(result){
    console.log(result);


    }
```

I am getting the alert value correctly but inside the ajax call i am not getting the output.

Comment: have you tried by using some dummy data like  data:'abc' is your ajax call is working?

Comment: yes.but i didn't get any output.......
The ajax call is working

Comment: Whai is your ajax file code ? i mean this file code "<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/dt-the7/home.php" ?

Comment: its using php...

Answer (score 0):

Seems your ajax request unsuccessfull every time. Try to add errors handling:

```
var name = this.value ;
alert(name);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
   url: "<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/dt-the7/home.php",
   data :name,
   success: function(result){
      console.log(result);
   }
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    console.log(xhr.status);
    console.log(thrownError);
  }
```

Comment: change console.log(result); to console.log("Result is:" + result); to see if result is just empty

Comment: so it means your script /wp-content/themes/dt-the7/home.php returns empty result

Comment: It shows other dummy  value outputs.but the data output is not showing

Comment: btw get_site_url() will return your site domain or something else? because you could violate crossorigin policy if domains are different